# Expose table in Drupal View

Tags: views

How can I expose a table with out primary key in Drupal view 3
I have table st as uid, gid, percentage.

```
attendance_views_data() {  

$data['attendance_percentage']['table']['group'] = t('Attendance');


    $data['attendance_percentage']['percentage'] = array(
        'title' => t('Attendance percentage field'),  
    'group' => t('Attendance'),
        'help' => t('Attendance percentage field.'), 
        'field' => array(
            'handler' => 'views_handler_field_numeric', 
            'click sortable' => TRUE,
            ), 
        'filter' => array(
            'handler' => 'views_handler_filter_numeric',
            ), 
        'sort' => array(
            'handler' => 'views_handler_sort',
            ),
    );
}
```

The above code does not work as I can not see percentage field in my view feild.

Comment: Is this Views 2 or Views 3? You have "Views 3" in your question and "Views 2" as a tag ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A problem in your code is that you are missing

```
return $data;
```

You also need to define the base for the table:

```
$data['attendance_percentage']['table']['base'] = array(
  'title' => t('Attendance'),
);
```

Should be enough.

Also remember you need to clear cache.